# Vim - Substitute command and regexp

Tags: vim

I have a little JSON files with some entries, here is a section:

```
"i":{
    "normale":"3c",
    "bold":"4b",
    "doppio":"6c"},
"is":{
    "normale":"2c",
    "bold":"33",
    "doppio":"66"},
```

I realized I have to add "\u25" in front of all the values, so I tried this command:

`:%s:\("\)\(\d\d"\)\|\("\)\(\d\w"\):"\\u25\2`

The idea is to search for either "dd" or "dw", and substitute the first double quote with `"\u25` while keeping the rest.This is the result:

```
"i":{
        "normale":"\u25,
        "bold":"\u25,
        "doppio":"\u25},
    "is":{
        "normale":"\u25,
        "bold":"\u2533",
        "doppio":"\u2566"},
```

If the matching string has only the two digits, the command works fine: the first double quote (the first group) is substituted and the second group is left as it was.
However, if the matching string has a digit and a character, it seems to ignore the second group, substituting the whole string. The two patterns are identical, except for `\w`, so it should work exactly the same. What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim matches `\d` to digits; you'd need `\x` to match hex digits.

But it seems you want to replace all occurrences of `:"` with `:"\u25`.

Can you use:

`:%s/:"/:"\\u25"/`

Or, if you want to prepend `\u25` to all occurrences of 2 hex digits,

`:%s/\x\x/\\u25&/`

Comment: Aha! Nice and clean, I didn't realized that. So, maybe my command didn't work because "dw" it's recognized as an hex character instead of "a digit with a following character"

Comment: Because `\d` matches decimal digits, and `\x` matches hex digits?